# Display different Vuejs components for mobile browsers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am developing an SPA using Vue 2.0. The components developed so far are for the "desktop" browsers, for example, I have

Main.vue,
ProductList.vue,
ProductDetail.vue,

I want another set of components for the mobile browsers, such as
MainMobile.vue,
ProductListMobile.vue,
ProductDetailMobile.vue,

My question is, where and how do I make my SPA render the mobile version of components when viewing in a mobile browser?

Please note that I explicitly want to **avoid** making my components responsive. I want to keep two separate versions of them.

Thanks,

Comment: for breakpoint detection, have a look here https://github.com/AlexandreBonaventure/vue-mq

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I have an idea, use a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) which detects if the browser is opened on mobile or desktop (example for js code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)). then use v-if, for example:

```html
<production-list v-if="!isMobile()"></production-list>
<production-list-mobile v-else></production-list-mobile>
```

so here is an example on https://jsfiddle.net/Ldku0xec/

Comment: You could also use named views and apply isMobile logic on <router-view> instance to avoid duplicating this logic on every component.

Comment: Can also use `v-if` and `v-else`, which I'd certainly prefer.

Answer (score 68):

I have simple solution for **Vue.js**:

```
<div v-if="!isMobile()">
  <desktop>
  </desktop>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <mobile>
  </mobile>
</div>
```

And methods:

```
methods: {
 isMobile() {
   if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
     return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: there is a syntax error  after iPhone (| instead of ||)

Comment: it's good but use `return ...` instead of a `if (...) { return true } else { return false }`

Comment: I've been doing some research and apparently it's rarely a good idea to use user agent sniffing for mobile device detection. I would refer you to the following documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent, where you can look for the "Mobile device detection" section. It shows you how to detect a mobile device by checking whether or not it has a touch screen, falling back to user agent sniffing only as a last resort. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it pick up say a laptop that is a touch screen device? I feel like that would be a problem

Answer (score 25):

I had this same problem, I solved it using a neutral and no layout vue file (Init.vue) that will be accessed by mobile and desktop, and this file redirects to the correct file.

Let's suppose that I have the Main.vue and the MainMobile.vue. I will add an Init.vue that will redirect. So my router/index.js is that:

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import MainMobile from '@/components/MainMobile'
import Init from '@/components/Init'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
     {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Root',
        component: Init
     },
    {
      path: '/Main',
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main
    },
    {
      path: '/MainMobile',
      name: 'MainMobile',
      component: MainMobile
    },
  ]
})
```

At the Init.vue file, the mobile/desktop detection will happen:

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Init',
        methods: {
            isMobile() {
                if( screen.width <= 760 ) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            if (this.isMobile()) {
                this.$router.push('/MainMobile');
            }
            else {
                this.$router.push('/Main');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The isMobile() function used is very simple, you can change to any other.

Comment: Best solution in my opinion. This way you can use the real screen size which is much more secure and efficient than checking the user agent/device/what ever.

Comment: @Brotzka I think you can not say it is best solution just because it does fit your needs. If you really want to know if the device is mobile then you can not check just the size of a screen.

Comment: instead of return true else return false, simply do: return screen.width <= 760

Answer (score 13):

I was looking for a solution for this and came here but I couldn't find what I needed:

1. Asynchronous imports to only load into the bundle what was needed based on the viewport.
2. Capability to serve a different layout if the layout was resized

I mixed and matched a few things I read online including answers here so I thought I'd just come back and put all my learnings into one function for anyone else looking:

```
/**
 * Breakpoint configuration to be in line with element-ui's standards
 * @type {{LABELS: string[], VALUES: number[]}}
 */
const BREAKPOINTS = {
    LABELS: ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'],
    VALUES: [0, 768, 992, 1200, 1920, Infinity]
};


/**
 * @typedef ViewFactory
 * @type function
 * A function which returns a promise which resolves to a view. Used to dynamically fetch a view file on the fly during
 * run time on a need basis
 */


/**
 * A helper to get a responsive route factory which renders different views based on the current view point
 * @param {{xs:[ViewFactory],sm:[ViewFactory],md:[ViewFactory],lg:[ViewFactory]}} map - A map of breakpoint key to a ViewFactory
 * @returns {ViewFactory} - A view factory which invokes and returns an item supplied in the map based on the current viewport size
 */
export default function responsiveRoute(map) {
    return function getResponsiveView() {
        const screenWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        // Find the matching index for the current screen width
        const matchIndex = BREAKPOINTS.VALUES.findIndex((item, idx) => {
            if (idx === 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return screenWidth >= BREAKPOINTS.VALUES[idx - 1] && screenWidth < BREAKPOINTS.VALUES[idx];
        }) - 1;


        if (map[BREAKPOINTS.LABELS[matchIndex]]) {
            // Perfect match, use it
            return map[BREAKPOINTS.LABELS[matchIndex]]();
        } else {
            // Go down the responsive break points list until a match is found
            let counter = matchIndex;
            while (counter-- > 0) {
                if (map[BREAKPOINTS.LABELS[counter]]) {
                    return map[BREAKPOINTS.LABELS[counter]]();
                }
            }
            return Promise.reject({
                code: 500,
                info: 'No component matched the breakpoint - probably a configuration error'
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes:[{
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: responsiveRoute({
          // route level code-splitting
          // this generates a separate chunk (login-xs.[hash].js) for this route
          // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
          xs: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login-xs" */ './views/Login/Login-xs.vue'),
          // sm key is missing, it falls back to xs
          md: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "login-md" */ './views/Login/Login-md.vue')
          // lg, xl keys are missing falls back to md
      }) 
  }]
});
```

How it works:

Vue Router supports defining the `component` key as a function which returns a promise to support async routes. The most common way being to use the webpack `import()` function which returns a promise. The function which returns the promise is only invoked when the route is about to be rendered ensuring we can lazy load our components

The `responsiveRoute` function accepts a map of these functions with keys set for different breakpoints and returns a function which, when invoked, checks the available viewport size and returns invokes the correct promise factory and return's the promise returned by it.

Notes:

I like this method because it does not require the application architecture or route configurations to be in a certain way. It's pretty plug and play using Vue Router capabilities provided out of the box. It also does not force you to define a view for every breakpoint-route combination. You can define a route as usual without this(lazy loaded or not) along side other routes that use this without any problems.

This method does not use user agent sniffing but uses the available width of the `document.documentElement` instead. Other methods I saw recommended things like `window.screen.width` which gives the exact device screen size regardless of the window size or a more robust `window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth`. Mix and match as needed.

My break points are (number and their values) are based on element-ui breakpoints as I used that for normal responsive design. This can again be configured as needed by changing the constants at the top

Comment: Nice!  Thank you for posting this.

Comment: pretty cool solution

Answer (score 9):

A bit late for this but, in case if any of you are looking to bind watchers for the viewport size, 
and/or check whenever the page loads. 
Its a lot of boilerplate to write but can be useful for small applications.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    isMobile: false
  }),

  beforeDestroy () {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.onResize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
  },

  methods: {
    onResize () {
      this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 600
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: guess there is no way to prevent showing the element on reload for a second before device detection grips...

Comment: isnt this resizelistener heavy? a resize observer with a cross browser polyfill would be much better IMO

Answer (score 9):

For vuetify users, you can use [breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/) with [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) loading. Suppose you have two components; DesktopLayout.vue and MobileLayout.vue. In the page where you want to load different layouts, define a dynamic component like this;

```
<component :is="currentComponent"></component>
```

Add a computed property named "currentComponent".

```
computed: {
    currentComponent() {
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly
            ? "MobileLayout"
            : "DesktopLayout";
    }
}
```

`this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly` will make use "MobileLayout" only on extra small screens. There are many breakpoints defined in vuetify. For example you can select a range by using "mdAndDown" for medium size and down screens.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 5):

An extended version of Beaudinn Greves answer:

- Use named router views
- listen on window resize and set isMobile true if width smaller then xy
- in router.js use "components" instead of "component" and import (you may use require) the desktop and mobile components

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container grid-lg">
    <router-view v-if="!store.app.isMobile"/>
    <router-view v-else name="mobile"/>
  </div>
</template>
...
name: "app",
  data: function() {
  return {
    store: this.$store.state
  };
},
mounted () {
  this.onResize()
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
},
methods: {
  onResize () {
    this.store.app.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 600
  }
},
beforeDestroy () {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize, { passive: true })
  }
}
```

router.js:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    components: {
      default: Home,
      mobile: HomeMobile
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is the best method if two page is completely different for PC and Mobile

Comment: @EscapeNetscape I tried your solution but it didn't work out :/ I mean, the state of isMobile is being saved in the data prop "Store" but I can't make it work for the Router.js to render the default or the mobile component based in the global prop "store" you know?

Comment: @juanpablob you just have to adapt to your code and your way of storing data. Most use vuex, I use a different approach for using a global store.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late for this but, in case if any of you are looking for I handled the situation like this:
I added meta to my router:

```js
const router = new Router({
     routes: [{
      path: '/main-view
      name: 'mainView',
      component: MainView,
      meta: {
        'hasMobileView': true
      }
     },
    {
     path: '/mobile-view',
      name: 'mobileView',
      component: mobileView,
      meta: {
        'hasDesktopView': true
      }
     },
    }]
})

then on beforeeach function 

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const hasMobileView = to.matched.some((route) => route.meta.hasMobileView)
  if (hasMobileView) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
      navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
      next('/mobile-view')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
})`
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution.In src/main.js:

```
 if (condition) {
    require('./pc/main)
 }else {
    require('./mobile/main')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply get user agent and parse it and then you have a variable isMobile
i assume you have it in this answer and i want to mention an important thing when you import both components (desktop and mobile) when user visit your page they both will download oh my God!!!

the solution is :

```
<template>
 <component :is="headerInstance" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
computed: {
    headerInstance() {
      const component = this.isMobile
        ? '/HeaderMobile'
        : '/HeaderDesktop'
      return () => import(`@/components/Layouts/Header${component}`)
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### resources/js/components/Options.vue

```html
<template>
    <div class="text-right mt-6 ml-16 fixed">
        <div v-if="isMobile()" class="px-0.5 py-0.5 hidden portrait:block">
            {/* ... */}
        </div>
        <div v-else class="px-0.5 py-0.5">
            {/* ... */}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            isMobile() {
                if ('maxTouchPoints' in navigator) return navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ? true : false
                else return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            screens: {
                'portrait': {'raw': '(orientation: portrait)'},
            }
        }
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {}
    },
    plugins: []
}
```

#### Desktop wide

[image: Desktop wide]

#### Desktop small

[image: Desktop small]

#### Mobile portrait

[image: Mobile portrait]

### Mobile landscape

[image: Mobile landscape]

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if is mobile

```
const isMobile=() =>( window.innerWidth <= 760 )
```