# How to import the folder as Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to display different Vue component for the mobile device. And I found this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48515205/11079653) via mixin.

And, for example, I have the component - Card.vue. But for the mobile device, I have created CardMovile.Vue.

Now I want to put these components in the folder Card which will contain index.js

```
-Card
--Card.vue
--CardMobile.vue
--index.js
```

After that, I just want import Card in my App.vue and index.js should decide what component needed (Card.vue or Card.mobile.vue)

```
<template>
  <Card></Card>
</template>

<script>
import Card from './Card'
</script>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to write the following in the `Card/index.js` file:

```
import isMobile from 'is-mobile'

import Card from './Card.vue'
import CardMobile from './CardMobile.vue'

export default isMobile() ? CardMobile : Card
```

Comment: Note that I use the npm package `is-mobile` in this example but feel free to use whatever function you'd like to detect a mobile browser